# Does deleting App Engine standard environment instances have any effect on billing?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-standard

We have an App Engine standard environment with automatic scaling. When we release a new version we allocate traffic to it and manually delete instances on the old version to save money. This seems a sensible thing to do but since reading the docs I'm wondering if this is in fact a waste of time.

The [App Engine pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) states that for basic or automatic scaling:

> accrual ends fifteen minutes after an instance finishes processing its last request

This makes it unclear if manually deleting instances actually has any effect on costs when using automatic scaling (which we do). Perhaps when calculating your bill they just look at the last request time and add 15 minutes to calculate your bill regardless of if the instance was deleted?

Answer (score 0):

In the same document you shared is pointed:

"Accrual of instance hours begins when an instance starts and ends as described below, depending on the type of scaling you specify for the instance"

I understand that no matters if you are deleting the instances manually if you set automatic scaling on your instance, this specification is going to be taken for calculate the accrual of instance hours, I think you could try to perform some tests with manual scaling.